# Como criar um arquivo CSV com os valores dos pixels de uma imagem

Tags: python, csv, opencv

Estou com problema em obter os dados dos valores dos *pixels* de uma imagem e escrever em um arquivo CSV, segue o código atual. O erro está no `.writerow`, porem não consigo identificar como alterar para funcionar.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import csv

img = cv2.imread('frame22.png',0)

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

erosion = cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1, borderValue=1)

dilationcomerosion = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel,iterations = 1, borderValue=-1)


cv2.namedWindow("Input", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.namedWindow("dilationcomerosion", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow('Input', img)
cv2.imshow('dilationcomerosion', erosion)

rows, cols = img.shape

with open('mycsv.csv', 'w') as f:

    thewriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

    for i in range(rows):

        for j in range(cols):

            k = img[i,j]

            thewriter.writerow(k)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Qual erro você recebe?

Comment: Opa cara consegui encontrar outra forma de visualizar o que era nescessario utilziando esse codigo, como uso o PyCharm eu apenas uso o Debug e visualizo a variavel como array. Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Em `thewriter.writerow(k)` não vejo a variável `k` no seu programa. Tente utilizar `thewriter.writerow(nome_da_variável)` com uma variável com os dados que serão escritos no arquivo csv. Mas um pixel é um array of arrays, então como você mencionou, é melhor visualizar no Pycharm ou com uma biblioteca de visualização de imagens e gráficos.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro alterar o pipeline de gravação do arquivo csv. O método *writerow()* espera um iterável, mas o *for* está retornando um objeto Numpy.

```
with open('mycsv.csv', 'w') as f:
    for x in range(rows):
        for y in range(cols):
            pixValue = img[x, y]
            f.write("{0}\n".format(pixValue))
```

Outra forma simples de resolver, seria passar um iterável (lista) para o método *writerow()*.

De:

```
thewriter.writerow(k)
```

Para:

```
thewriter.writerow([k])
```

Comment: Considere incluir uma breve explicação a respeito da sua solução.

Comment: Feito. Obrigado @MarcellAlves.